# C++ thread-safe object pool

Tags: c++, memory-management, thread-safety

This is a modern C++ implementation of a **thread-safe memory pool** -- I want to make sure I am solving the *critical section problem* correctly (no deadlocks, starvation, bounded waiting) and I am getting details like [the rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) correct (copy not allowed, move doesn't trigger double release). Design criteria:

- Small number of items in pool (e.g. 5 to 10) since each may have a large memory footprint -- the number can be decided / fixed when the pool is created.
- Uses RAII to guarantee an object is released when code leaves scope.
- If there are no items available in the pool, the code blocks until one is available.

The typical usage pattern would be:

```
ObjectPool<Foo> pool(5, Foo_ctor_args);
...
{
     ObjectPool<Foo>::Item foo = pool.acquire()
     foo.object.doSomething();
}
```

Class template:

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <iostream>
    
    template <typename T>
    class ObjectPool {
    private:
        std::vector<T> objects;
        std::vector<bool> inUse;
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable cond;
    public:
        
        class Item {
        public:
            T& object;
            Item(T& o, size_t i, ObjectPool& p) : object{o}, index{i}, pool{p} {}
            Item(const Item&) = delete;
            Item(Item&& other) : object{other.object}, index{other.index}, pool{other.pool} {
                other.index = bogusIndex;  // <-- don't release
            }
            Item& operator=(const Item&) = delete;
            Item& operator=(Item&& other) {
                if (this != &other) {
                    object = other.object;
                    index = other.index;
                    pool = other.pool;
                    other.index = bogusIndex;  // <-- don't release
                }
                return *this;
            }
            ~Item() {
                if (index != bogusIndex) {
                    pool.release(index);
                    index = bogusIndex;  // <-- avoid double release
                }
            }
        private:
            constexpr static size_t bogusIndex = 65535;
            size_t index;
            ObjectPool<T>& pool;
        };
        
        template<typename... Args>
        ObjectPool(size_t maxElems, Args&&... args) : inUse(maxElems, false) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < maxElems; i++)
                objects.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        
        Item acquire() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
            while (true) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
                    if (!inUse[i]) {
                        inUse[i] = true;
                        return Item{objects[i], i, *this};
                    }
                cond.wait(guard);
            }
        }
    
    private:
        void release(size_t index) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
            assert(index < objects.size());
            assert(inUse[index]);
            inUse[index] = false;
            cond.notify_all();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Use `std::size_t` instead of `size_t`. Because `size_t` is implementation defined and can cause problems on different compilers.

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: What? I left the original code completely intact so folks can see the original version. I clearly marked the part that was improved from the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Only allow `ObjectPool` to create `Item`s

The rule of five is used correctly as far as I can see, but there are still some ways to create an incorrect `Item`, and use that to corrupt an existing `ObjectPool`. Consider:

```
ObjectPool<int> pool(10);
int value = 42;
decltype(foo)::Item item(value, 0, pool);
```

To prevent this from happening, make all constructors `private`, and make `Item` a `friend` of `ObjectPool`:

```
template <typename T>
class ObjectPool {
    ...
    class Item {
        friend ObjectPool;

        Item(T& o, size_t i, ObjectPool& p) : object{o}, index{i}, pool{p} {}
        Item(const Item&) = delete;
        Item(Item&& other) : object{other.object}, index{other.index}, pool{other.pool} {
            other.index = bogusIndex;  // <-- don't release
        }

    public:
        T& object;
        ...
    };
    ...
};
```

## Make `Item` work like a `std::unique_ptr`

An `Item` is almost like a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr); while the pool is the actual owner, `Item` acts like a unique *reference*. I would make the member variable `object` private, and instead add these member functions to access it:

```
T& operator*() {
    return object;
}

T* operator->() {
    return &object;
}

T* get() {
    return &object;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
auto foo = pool.acquire();
foo->doSomething();
```

## Consider adding a constructor that takes an initizalier list

An object pool is like a container. Consider that most STL containers allow initializing using a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), you might want to add that for your object pool, so that you could write something like:

```
ObjectPool<std::string> pool = {"foo", "bar", "baz", ...};
```

## Set `bogusIndex` to `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`

Even if you cannot think of a use case for an object pool of 65535 or more items now, consider that you might need it in the future, or someone else using your code might. If you are going to use a special value for `index` to indicate that an `Item` doesn't need to be released, give it a value that really can never be a valid index, like the maximum possible value for a `std::size_t`.

## Use `notify_one()`

When you release an `Item` back to the pool, it doesn't make sense to wake up all threads that are waiting. Only one will be able to get the `Item` that was just released. So use [`notify_one()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) instead.

## Consider supporting non-copyable value types

Since you store the objects in a `std::vector`, this requires `T` to be copy-assignable and copy-constructible. Consider storing them in some way that does not have this limitation, for example by using a [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead.

## `Item`'s move constructor should `std::move` the `object`

If you are moving one `Item` into another, it makes sense to also use move-assignment on `object`. It should be as simple as:

```
object = std::move(other.object)
```

## `acquire()` is an \$O(N)\$ operation

It is unfortunate that `acquire()` does a linear scan through `inUse[]`. It should be possible to turn this into an \$O(1)\$ operation. One possibility is to use a `std::set` to store the indices of the items that are in use, but while technically \$O(1)\$ amortized, that might involve a lot of unwanted allocations. There are other ways to keep track of this though.

Comment: Great. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for. I was paranoid about using `notify_one` but it certainly seems safe. I didn't know `std::deque` supported non-copyable types -- hmm. I wasn't worried about the linear access time, but speeding this up would allow other use cases. thanks!

Comment: I did the `std::unique_ptr` mimicry, but I made move ctor and move assignment public so user can move them around.  Return type not `Item` here:`T* operator->() {return &object;}`; Again ... thanks for the help there are great ideas.

Comment: Ah yes, that should be `T` not `Item`. Making the move constructor and assignment operator public is indeed fine.